# How to give Urdu as an input to the Java Program?

Tags: java, input, locale

I am new user. I want to make a program which takes user input in Urdu language and then that input is converted to English language. I just want to know that how can the input be set to the Urdu language, i.e., when the user gives input, it should be in Urdu language not in english characters.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `System.out.printf(Locale l,String format,Object ... args)`